# Happy belated birthday in Italian

Tags: phrase-request

How can I say happy birthday in Italian, when I missed the initial date and therefore am late to congratulate?

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that a simple "auguri in ritardo" will do the job. Of course you can build on this.

> "Scusami! Mi sono dimenticato di augurarti buon compleanno. Auguri in ritardo!"

Comment: I agree, "auguri in anticipo/ritardo" is probably the most common way to say it.

Comment: @Easymode44 Welcome on ItalianSE!

Comment: Although I eventually used the turtle response from Alberto Moor, I felt like accepting this answer because it seems like the more general, formal one.

Answer (score 6):

If it's a friend's birthday, you can reply jokingly

> Ho affidato i miei auguri per te ad una tartaruga... scusa il ritardo! Auguri!

or

> La cattiva notizia è che ho dimenticato di spedire in tempo il tuo biglietto d'auguri. La buona notizia è che ho dimenticato la tua età! Spero che tu abbia passato un felice compleanno!

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested in an extended or humorous phrasing, other have already answered. The more straightforward ways to say “Happy belated birthday” are:

> Buon compleanno in ritardo!

or

> (Tanti) auguri (di buon compleanno) in ritardo!

Answer (score 4):

I use the slightly different "ritardati auguri".

You can find [here](https://www.auguribuoncompleanno.org/auguri-di-compleanno-in-ritardo/) a jokely list of wishes in case you are late.

Comment: _Ritardato_ in italiano is rarely used for “late”, while it also carries the meaning of “retard”...